# Make use of binary operation sign in a variable

Tags: python

My question is if i have a variable called op which can contain a plus sign, minus sign etc, how can i make use of that op variable to make a calculation? Instead of having multiple if statements how can i do something like this instead

```
if op in ['+','-', '*', '/']:
    return x op y
else:
    print("ERROR")
```

instead of having for example

```
if op == "+":
    return x + y
elif op == "-":
    return x - y
....
....
```

I have tried making op an int but it doesnt work, is there a solution for this or do i have to check if op is any of the possible signs?

EDIT:
How can i do the same with a bigger than, smaller than or equal sign?

To check is op is any of these `["=","<",">"]

Comment: Ok thanks, how can i do the same with a bigger than, smaller than or equal sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/operator.html) module.  It contains a function for every Python operator:

```
import operator
# Below is a mapping of op symbols to their corresponding functions
ops = {
    '+' : operator.add, 
    '-' : operator.sub, 
    '*' : operator.mul, 
    '/' : operator.truediv, 
    '==' : operator.eq, 
    '>' : operator.gt, 
    '<' : operator.lt
}
def func(op, x, y):
    try:
        return ops[op](x, y)
    except KeyError:
        return 'ERROR'
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> func('+', 2, 1)
3
>>> func('-', 2, 1)
1
>>> func('*', 2, 1)
2
>>> func('/', 2, 1)
2.0
>>> func('==', 2, 1)
False
>>> func('>', 2, 1)
True
>>> func('<', 2, 1)
False
>>> func('&', 2, 1) # Just to demonstrate
'ERROR'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a map from the symbol to the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) function that corresponds to the op:

```
import operator
ops = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul, 
    '/': operator.div,
}
```

And then:

```
def apply_op(op, val1, val2):
    return ops[op](val1, val2)
```

Comment: Beat me to it, and explained it more concisely to boot.

Comment: But one thing: `div` may not be what you want. If you're trying to match the actual equivalent Python expression, which may be truediv or floordiv depending on Python version and possible `__future__` statement, it's `div`; if you want one or the other explicitly, it's better to use `truediv` or `floordiv` directly.

Comment: @abarnert: ah good point! i assumed the OP wanted the equivalent of textual substitution, which would be `.div`

Comment: I thought so at first too, until I noticed that he also wanted `=`, not `==`, to map to equality… which made me suspect he's really just trying to build a calculator, and the textual substitution was just a guess at what might be an easy way to do what he wants, rather than what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
eval('%d %s %d' % (x, op, y))
```

Edit: depends on triviality of the question,
You would

```
assert isinstance(x, int)
assert isinstance(y, int)
```

Comment: Ok cool, this works great, but where does the letters come from, d is for int? and s for string?

Comment: You should not do this. If, for instance, the user inputs `x` as `__import__("subprocess").Popen("rm -rf", shell=True)` your hard drive will be wiped.

Comment: Well, as written, that will cause an exception because `__import__` etc isn't a valid value for %d. But the other answers are better.

Comment: No, eval will never run, as it's the `'%d %s %d' % (x, op, y)` part that raises the exception.

Comment: Anyway the better way to solve the problem is the visitor pattern.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Ah, right, he's doing the `eval` around the whole thing. So the user would have to input that for `op` instead of `x`, which is… still completely insecure.